# How to add prebuilt shared library in aosp system apps

Tags: android, android-source, android.mk

My structure is

```
  packages/apps/myapp //No Java source file
   |
   Android.mk / first Makefile, 
   jni __
        |
        source.c 
        Android.mk // 2nd Makefile
        libs // Prebuilt libs
```

First Amdroid.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Second Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libabc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libabc.so
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)



include $(CLEAR_VARS)


LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    my_jni.c



LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    libabc \


LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    includes


LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := libmy_jni


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But this always gives me error :

```
make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/product/myproduct/obj/lib/libabc.so', needed by `out/target/product/myproduct/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libmy_jni_intermediates/LINKED/libmy_jni.so'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `mmm myapp`, this requires the aosp build objects that was created during an aosp build.

Comment: @t0mm13b nothing informational for me.

Comment: You do have `out/target/product/myproduct/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libvcs_jni_intermediates/LINKED/libmy_jni.so` present?

Comment: yes that is the issue, what is missing that do not let libabc to include or be at proper place.

Comment: Try removing the `LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE` line